# Issue converting datetime in sql 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

I am having an issue converting a datetime. Please see sql below. The format of the date in the db is 2014-06-30 00:00:00.000

I can get it to convert to dd/mm/yyyy and see this in the query result but when trying to run my report in bids i get: "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT     b.PREBILL_NUM, b.BILL_TYPE, b.BILL_NUM, b.TRAN_UNO,  CONVERT(date,b.BILL_DATE,103) as BILL_DATE, c.CLIENT_CODE, c.CLIENT_NAME, N.NAME, a.MATTER_UNO, m.MATTER_NUMBER, 
                      m.MATTER_NAME, m.CLNT_MATT_CODE, m.LONG_MATT_NAME, m._OLD_MATTER_CODE, m.BILL_EMPL_UNO, p.EMPLOYEE_CODE, p.EMPLOYEE_NAME, p.EMAIL, 
                      p.LOGIN
FROM         dbo.BLT_BILL AS b LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.BLT_BILLM AS a ON b.TRAN_UNO = a.BILL_TRAN_UNO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.HBM_MATTER AS m ON a.MATTER_UNO = m.MATTER_UNO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.HBM_CLIENT AS c ON c.CLIENT_UNO = m.CLIENT_UNO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.HBM_PERSNL AS p ON p.EMPL_UNO = m.BILL_EMPL_UNO LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.HBM_NAME AS N ON N.NAME_UNO = c.NAME_UNO
WHERE     (b.BILL_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND p.LOGIN LIKE @Username)
```

Comment: Your date is getting rendered in `SSRS` as the `string` you need to convert the value using the `Date Conversion` functions in SSRS .

Comment: do you really have format on your datetime in your database ? I should hope not. I would assume it has the type datetime (no format possible). How are StartDate and EndDate declared ?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `varchar` to `date` i.e. to convert from `2014-06-30 00:00:00.000` format to date you should use

```
CONVERT(date, '2014-06-30 00:00:00.000', 121)
```

also you can use

```
CAST('2014-06-30 00:00:00.000' as date)
```

because it is default format for `time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset`.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the select statement as below but still getting the same error. Can you have a look and modify please as required?

Comment: SELECT     b.PREBILL_NUM, b.BILL_TYPE, b.BILL_NUM, b.TRAN_UNO, Convert(nvarchar(10),CONVERT(date,b.BILL_DATE,121),103) as BILL_DATE, c.CLIENT_CODE, c.CLIENT_NAME, N.NAME, a.MATTER_UNO, m.MATTER_NUMBER,